# NFS - some files show as zero bytes

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have an NFSv3 Ubuntu server.

When I extract a specific zip file, it creates a folder and several files. The folder is accessible over NFS, and the names of all the files are there.  The only problem is that the files show as 0 bytes and won't open on my client.

If I create a new folder, and `cp` the files to it, they work!

I've run `ls -l` and `lsattr` - but I can't see any difference between the files.  `stat -c %a` shows `744` for both.

Both files have the correct size when I run `ls -l`.

I've rebooted both client and server, it doesn't make a difference.

I feel like I'm going crazy here. Is there any permission or attribute which could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a permissions issue with the parent folder.

Running `stat foldername/` showed the permissions were set to `744`

I fixed this by running `chmod 775 foldername/`

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me (I had changed the permissions on a directory where a USB that wouldn't let me add files to it was mounted and the USB contents directory turned into a 0 byte file.), but I cannot fathom how permissions could cause a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

If the directory is stored inside Zip without trailing '/' then it will be unzipped as a 0 byte file, if you run zip info you'll see that it's directory. cp is able to copy uziped files from this directory cause you target the files that have their inodes in the system. So the problems is with how you've zipped the file and its name. The directory specified for zipping must contain '/'. I think that you can edit zip and change name of directory to name/ to fix it.

Comment: To clarify, the file is larger than 0 bytes. If I use `ls -l` I can see that it several MB. It just shows as empty when accessed via NFS.

Comment: That's one of the faces of this bug :) Did my solution helped?

Comment: It did not help. Sorry.